# How to add space in string in c#

Tags: c#, prefix, suffix

I am using c sharp

I want to add some space suffix and prefix in my string `Advertising`

I have tried this without success

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string txt = "Advertising";
        string padrightleft = txt.ToString().PadRight(10, ' ').PadLeft(10, ' ').ToUpper();

        Response.Write(padrightleft.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: `.PadRight(10, ' ').PadLeft(10, ' ')` The 1st call will already have padded to 10 characters, so the 2nd won't do anything. But since the orginal is already longer than 10 characters the 1st is not doing anything either.. - And `txt.ToString()` is silly, too. 3x0 = 0 ;-)

Comment: Do you need to always add the same number of spaces to txt? If so, why not just do "          " + txt + "          "?

Comment: The word `Advertising` is 11 characters long, and you're trying to pad it to 10 characters. As it's longer than 10 characters it just returns the original string.

Comment: @redsoxfantom because not work if need inserted the string on table database

Comment: change right from 10 to 20, left from 10 to 29, try again.

Comment: Also, your usage of `Response.Write` suggest that the client is an HTML client - which is known to ignore multiple spaces and just replace them with a single space. You might want to pad with `&nbsp` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PadLeft` and `PadRight` will only add padding it the string is shorter that then number of padding characters you want to add. Since `Advertising` is 11 characters long and you are padding to 10 characters the string won't change.

If you just want to add a prefix and suffix to a piece of string then you can do this:

```
string txt = "Advertising";

var padding = new string(' ', 10);
var newText = string.Concat(padding, txt, padding);
```